# Setting up timezone for mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone

I want to setup time_zone for some other time zone different than that of my system like (GMT - 7:00). I tried

```
SET  time_zone  =  '-07:00';
```

But this changed it just for a MYSQL Session and is not permanent as the time_zone returns back to system time_zone after i restart mysql service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can retrieve the server and client time_zone settings:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

You can also change the client timezone, or the timezone for the entire MySQL instance.

If you have server time_zone set at MySQL instance startup, you can modify the /etc/my.cnf file (or wherever your mysql instance initialization parameters are read from), under the [mysqld] section:

```
[mysqld]
default-time-zone='+00:00'
```

-- or --

```
add the --default_time_zone='+00:00' option to mysqld_safe
```

WIth Each client session can change the timezone setting for their own session:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Tokyo';
```

(Or whatever time zone GMT+1 is.: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

This is the command to set the MySQL timezone for an individual client, assuming that your clients are spread accross multiple time zones.